# Box data div show on hover

Tags: jquery

i'm trying to make a grid with project boxes and I can't quite get it to show only the data div corresponding to said box. All the .data divs show on hover.

What am I missing? It's driving me crazy. Tried a few ways, I know i have to somehow select the "this .data" but it was giving me syntax errors.

Thanks in advance!!!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.box').each(function(){
 $(this).hover( 
    function () {
       console.log('entro');
       $('.box .data').css({"display":"block"});
    }, 
    function () {
       console.log('salgo');
       $('.box .data').css({"display":"none"});
    }
 );
  });
});
```

```html
echo "<div class='box' data-position='".$row->posicion."'>";
  echo "<div class='data'><h1>".$row->proyecto."</h1></div>";
  echo "<div class='imagen'><img src='".$row->thumbnail."'></div>";
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: do you want to like tooltip on mousehover

Comment: Something like that yes. I want the images to have a red overlay + a text of the project they're pointing at when you hover over each one. I'll look into that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you forget to add jQuery Library. Please check the below output. Is that sufficient for you?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.box').each(function(){
 $(this).hover( 
    function () {
       console.log('entro');
       $('.box .data').css({"display":"block"});
    }, 
    function () {
       console.log('salgo');
       $('.box .data').css({"display":"none"});
    }
 );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
echo "<div class='box' data-position='".$row->posicion."'>";
  echo "<div class='data'><h1>".$row->proyecto."</h1></div>";
  echo "<div class='imagen'><img src='".$row->thumbnail."'></div>";
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: I do have the library and more code, I just didn't put all of it for clarification purposes (this is a small part of the site). It still displays all .data boxes at once, sadly! It's something wrong with my jQuery event handling.